# How to connect Apollographql to multiple Postgres databases

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js, apollo-server

I would like to use [Apollographql](https://www.apollographql.com/) to connect multiple Postgres databases which share the same structures (tables, columns). The idea was having a single endpoint to access any of these databases (using namespaces), but I couldn't find in the documentation how to do this.

I need a bit of your wisdom guys, how can Apollo connect to multiple Postgres databases using different namespaces? Is there another app better suited for this kind of requirements?